# matplotlib: Add AxesSubplot instances to a figure

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I'm going insane here ... this should be a simple exercise but I'm stuck:

I have a Jupyter notebook and am using the [`ruptures`](https://github.com/deepcharles/ruptures) Python package. All I want to do is, take the figure or AxesSubplot(s) that the [`display()`](https://centre-borelli.github.io/ruptures-docs/code-reference/show/display/) function returns and add it to a figure of my own, so I can share the x-axis, have a single image, etc.:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

myfigure = plt.figure()
l = len(df.columns)
    
for index, series in enumerate(df):
        
    data = series.to_numpy().astype(int)

    algo = rpt.KernelCPD(kernel='rbf', min_size=4).fit(data)
    result = algo.predict(pen=3)

    myfigure.add_subplot(l, 1, index+1)
    rpt.display(data, result)

    plt.title(series.name)

    
plt.show()
```

What I get is a figure with the desired number of subplots (all empty) and *n* separate figures from `ruptures`:

[image: result of my code]

When instead I want want the subplots to be filled with the figures ...

Comment: Did you see the return value of `display`: (figure, axarr) with a :class:`matplotlib.figure.Figure` object and an array of Axes objects? You probably should work with those, not create your own subplots.

Comment: the `display` function from `ruptures` is hardwired to always create it's own Figure and Axes instances to plot on. Unfortunately, you can't transfer an Axes instance from one figure to another, so you will probably need to grab the reference to the Figure and Axes instances created by `display`, and manipulate those to your specification

Comment: @BigBen I've tried that, like this: `myfigure.axes.append(rpt.display(data, result)[1][0])` but no success ...

Comment: @tmdavison in the end I just recreate the plot that `display()` gave me (see my answer). Thank you for the hint, otherwise I would've wasted even more time pursuing that avenue :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I basically had to recreate the plot that `ruptures.display(data,result)` produces, to get my desired figure:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import ruptures as rpt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import EngFormatter

fig, axs = plt.subplots(len(df.columns), figsize=(22,20), dpi=300)

for index, series in enumerate(df):
    
    resampled = df[series].dropna().resample('6H').mean().pad()
    data = resampled.to_numpy().astype(int)
    
    algo = rpt.KernelCPD(kernel='rbf', min_size=4).fit(data)
    result = algo.predict(pen=3)
    
    # Create ndarray of tuples from the result
    result = np.insert(result, 0, 0) # Insert 0 as first result
    tuples = np.array([ result[i:i+2] for i in range(len(result)-1) ])
    
    ax = axs[index]
    
    # Fill area beween results alternating blue/red
    for i, tup in enumerate(tuples):
        if i%2==0:
            ax.axvspan(tup[0], tup[1], lw=0, alpha=.25)
        else:
            ax.axvspan(tup[0], tup[1], lw=0, alpha=.25, color='red')
    
    ax.plot(data)
    ax.set_title(series)
    ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(EngFormatter())


plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=.3)
plt.show()
```

I've wasted more time on this than I can justify, but it's pretty now and I can sleep well tonight :D

[image]